# What are some good vocoders to use?

Tags: vocoder, style, suggestions, effects

Hi everyone.  I am wondering if there are any vocoders that come recommended by people at this forum.  Right now, I am working on a project for a video game.  The hits, I want to be vocoded with a synth sound and so I am looking for vocoders.  Are there any suggestions out there?

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to suggest my personal favourite, [Image-Line's Vocodex](http://www.image-line.com/plugins/Effects/Vocodex/). Nice routing and tweaking options, and it's not too expensive either, sitting at 99 USD :)

Answer (score 1):

I like the [BV512 Vocoder](https://www.propellerheads.se/products/reason/index.cfm?fuseaction=get_article&article=devices_bv512) included in Reason, though something to look at when shopping around for vocoders is the maximum number of bands.  512 bands (hence BV**512**) is pretty sufficient for most of the sound design I do, but there are times that I wish I had more; e.g., 1024 bands.

Generally speaking, the greater number of bands available, the more closely your input sound will resemble the modifier.  Judging by your profile, I'm sure you're already aware of this relationship.  That said, if you're a Kyma user, you can use as many bands as your hardware will allow.  If that's an option for you, it's definitely worth exploring.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Prosoniq’s OrangeVocoder. I really love it. 
http://www.prosoniq.com

Answer (score 0):

I use [this](http://www.ehx.com/products/v256) every day at work, and I'll happily recommend it.  It's definitely a bang-for-your-buck option.

Answer (score 0):

My favorite was Vokator but NI discontinued it. Why... oh why..

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to get some pretty cool sounding vocals with Waves Morphoder.